# IP addresses from public IP block in my LAN

Tags: ip, nat, lan

If I have NAT or PAT applied on edge router, Would it matter if I use IP addresses from public block in my LAN? And how?

Comment: Are they from a block you own and that's routed to your LAN? Then it would possibly make sense and you do *not* need NAT to route the IPs.

Comment: No, well, not owned.
I see you answer below.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 17):

EDITED

I'm assuming you're considering using an IP block that is not registered to you. Otherwise, skip to the last paragraph.

Besides being a very poor practice, if you use public addresses on your internal network, that means that you can never reach hosts that use those real addresses.  You may think you'll never need to reach servers in some other part of the world, but you'd be surprised at how often that happens.

BTW, if you don't use NAT, you're essentially hijacking someone else's addresses, and your ISP may disconnect you from the Internet (among other things).

The RFC 1918 addresses (10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, and 192.168.0.0/16) should provide plenty of address space for your internal network.

If you are using your own IP block, then there's nothing wrong with using those addresses internally.  It may possibly increase your security risks, but those can be mitigated by other means.

Comment: Also note that non-RFC1918 addresses used inside your network wreak havoc with many security monitoring/intrusion detection systems. As far as the appliances are concerned, those are internet addresses which means those are internet originated packets bouncing around your LAN. Alarm bells ensue.

Comment: There's also the issue of reverse DNS lookups.  For example, if you gave one of your computers the IP address `172.217.14.196`, it'll show up in various places with the name `sea30s01-in-f4.1e100.net`.

Comment: *Even if you use NAT*, it's very possible to have a router/NAT/firewall configuration that will send your LAN packets using public addresses out to the internet.

Comment: And of course, the fact that you can't access those hosts on the Internet is the *reason* it's a very poor practice.

Comment: Although it's extremely unusual, there is a special case where this would be legitimate: your network has properly assigned "public" IP addresses and those are what you are using.  And for some reason you're also using PAT/NAT, perhaps to cloak your internal structure, perhaps to merge with another organisation's addressing.  I've never seen this, and don't expect to!

Comment: @jonathanjo Actually I’ve seen it several times. . My current client uses their assigned block internally, and I’ve had other clients in the past who do that as well. They’re mostly government agencies who had large allocations from the days when IPs were plentiful.

Comment: It's worth noting that all the IP addresses in the network, as configured on the various devices on the LAN, will not be reachable on the public internet, not just the IP addresses actually used. So if one where to configure 172.217.14.196/16 on a computer, none of the IP addresses in 172.217.*.* would be reachable, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

It matters in the situation that you do not need/want to reach those public IPs used.

If you use such IPs and then you, for example, want to access a site that has one of the IPs, it will not work, because your IP will resolve locally instead of going through your edge router and forward.

My company also uses such a system (it was implemented this way to be able to connect to other partner locations via EIGRP) and the corresponding IPs are assigned to China, so things should be fine as the company does not deal anything directly with something in hosted in China.